# Public Java Class or Jar

Tags: java, class, jar, public

I'm looking to create a universal logging file for all of my companies Java applications. I've done something similiar in C++, where you simply import the file.

My question is, what is the most effective/efficent way to create a public Java file (basically what do you create it as, and then how do you reference it)? I'm assuming its by importing your own class or jar? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what you mean, but it *sounds* like you're trying to create a library to be used by multiple applications.

I'd suggest that the other projects should simply refer to it as a jar file - whether they build that jar file from source or fetch one from some company-wide repository which is updated when the logging code changes is up to you. From the application code, you'd just import it as any other class - whether the class is found in a jar file or as a .java file is irrelevant in the consuming Java source code.

It's worth noting that there are already *many* other logging APIs for Java - I would think very carefully before you create a new one.

Comment: Some of those logging APIs are easy but less configurable, some are powerful but harder to figure out. Now, most developers I know could write their own logging API faster than they could learn a new one. But I don't know any that can write *and debug* their own faster than they could learn one!

Comment: @glowcoder: Exactly - something like log4j is really battle-hardened.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!

Edit: I guess I'll bring up the debate of whether to create our own or learn an existing one after I look more into it.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you don't import the file you import the class. The class that is imported is either in a compiled `.class` file or packaged in a `.jar` file. By convention, package your logger utilities in a `.jar` and distribute that.

You import the class by name regardless if it's yet to be compiled from a source file or already packaged in a `.jar`.